# Is $f'>0$ enough for Newton's method to converge?

Tags: newton-raphson

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is smooth, that it has a root and that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Does this guarantee that Newton's method will converge (quadratically) for all choices of initial points?

Comment: These days you need to explain more about where you got the problem from and what have you tried, so your question will not be closed by the moderators.

Comment: @Momo Yes, thank you.

Comment: Also not strictly related, because it's not always increasing, but this answer from the other day might be interesting. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314240/example-of-numerical-methods#4314428